# Does the Windows Live Mail client support IMAP flags?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, label, flag

Thunderbird and Opera both support IMAP flags ("labels"), like: "important", "work", "later", and custom labels too ("myown", "archive").

I tried to use Windows Live Mail, but I don't see a similar function. Is this supported?

Comment: Windows Live mail does support Imap.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between Windows Mail and Windows Live Mail.